# Simple battery pack question

Tags: batteries

I have three Nitecore NL147 14500 Li-ion Rechargeable Batteries 750mAh 3.7V 2.8Wh in a 11.1 volt pack.

Am I correct to say that my battery pack is 750mAh and 8.325Wh ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you making us try to reproduce your math? Please explain how you found your answer.

Comment: Single battery .75Ah x 3.7V = 2.8Wh.  Three batteries .75Ah x 3 x 3.7V = 8.325Wh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying the amp hours by the voltage is does not give you Watt hours. This is because the voltage of the pack drops during discharge, meaning it's not a flat 3.7v over the whole 0.75Ah. To figure out the exact Watt hours the pack would need discharged while recording the current and voltage of the pack. The readings would then be integrated to give you the packs Watt hours.